# Can't change select value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I've got a very simple select defined like this :

```
<select name='typedoc' id ='typedoc' size=1>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

There are 2 values, `1` and `2`. Display is OK. I can't change the value with jQuery. I tried :

```
$('[name=typedoc]').val('2');
```

and

```
$('#typedoc').val('2');
```

But the ddl stays on the first choice. The lines before are executed, so I'm sure the function is called. What could be wrong?

Comment: This works fine; http://jsfiddle.net/LX5ym/. You ***need*** to come up with more info... are you wrapping in `$(document).ready()`? Are you loading the `<select>` by AJAX? Show us more code/ come up with a reduced example on http://jsfiddle.net which reproduces your problem.

Comment: this is dropdown list for select or input text field?

Comment: Could you post the full HTML of your `<select>`, including the `<option>` elements in it.

Comment: do you want to change the actual value in the <option>-tag or do you want to mark another option as selected? 

Please provide some more code.

Comment: Should work. Post more code or an example.

Answer (score 6):

Since your question is not very clear, I am going to presume that you want one for following 3 solutions,

```
//To change the value of the option
$('[name=typedoc] option[value=2]').val('3'); 

//To select option with value = 3
$('[name=typedoc] option[value=3]').prop('selected',true);

//To Change the text of the option with value = 3
$('[name=typedoc] option[value=3]').text('Third');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too solved it by using this:

```
$('#typedoc option[value="2"]').prop('selected',true);
```

Obviously you can substitute the value dynamically by editing the selector string

Comment: Problem solved : I had a typo I couldn't see for an hour . Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @AlexLeguevaques if you solved the problem, and nobody gave that as an answer, please post it as an answer and select it as the answer. Otherwise, choose someone's answer so the question is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, check your markup for syntax errors

**HTML:**

```
<select name='typedoc' id ='typedoc' size=1>
    <option value="1" >1</option> 
    <option value="2" >2</option>     
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('[name=typedoc]').val('2');
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uyD5J/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
<select name='typedoc' id ='typedoc' size=1>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

jquery is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('[name=typedoc]').val('4');
});
```

Comment: I had a typo in my code I couldn'see for an hour. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.val()`, use `$('#typedoc option[value="2"]').attr('selected', true)`

Comment: For that to work you'll need to identify the individual `<option>` element rather than the `<select>` element that contains them.

Comment: You're correct... that part didn't get copied while I was composing...  Just fixed with edit

Answer (score 0):

Works for me .... check your markup or give more details ...

http://jsfiddle.net/uTkyE/1/